# Convention of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-series

I am trying understand derivation of fourier series from $2\pi$-periodic funtions to $T$-periodic functions. Here, this is for $2\pi$-periodic functions

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int _{-\pi}^{\pi} x(t^*)\,e^{-jnt^*} dt^* = X(n)$$
$$x(t^*)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\sum _{n=-\infty}^{\infty}X(n)\,e^{jnt^*}$$

Which is I totally understood reasoning behind it. I converted them by using following relation.
$$\frac{t^*}{2\pi} = \frac{t}{T}$$
Finally I got this:
$$x(t) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} X(n) \, e^{j\frac{2\pi}{T}nt}$$
$$X(n) = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{T}\int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} x(t) \, e^{-jn\frac{2\pi}{T} t} \, dt$$

However, in my class notes, it was written without $\sqrt{2\pi}$ coefficient, so it is like transforming ${\sqrt{2\pi}} x(t)$ to $X(n)$ instead of $x(t)$ to $X(n)$. My question is why there is such difference? And does not it cause an error?

**Edit**: My class notes:
$$x(t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} X(n) \, e^{j\frac{2\pi}{T} nt}$$
$$X(n) = \frac{1}{T} \int_{-\frac{T}{2}}^{\frac{T}{2}} x(t) \, e^{-jn\frac{2\pi}{T} t} \, dt$$

Comment: The difference is the presence or absence of $2\pi$ in the exponent.

Comment: @herbsteinberg I edited the question.There was little mistake. 2*pi in exponent comes from relation I mentioned it. I was not asking it actually

Comment: Just let $Y(n) =X(n)/\sqrt{2\pi}$.

Comment: @EnesErdogan I was trying to answer your original question about the presence of $\sqrt{2\pi}$ in your derivation that was not in your class notes.  Other comment hopefully clarifies.